# Conocer qué navegador utiliza un usuario

Tags: php

Estoy utilizando

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Para conocer qué navegador utiliza un usuario del sistema pero al ejecutar el script desde diversos navegadores muestra casi el mismo mensaje:
En Chrome:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36
```

En Mozilla/Firefox:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
```

En Internet Explorer:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

En Brave:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
```

Existe alguna manera de identificar mejor cada navegador?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes el método `get_browser` además de poder utilizar `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$navegador = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($navegador);

?>
```

No solo te da información del navegador y su versión sino de la plataforma, entre otras cosas, obtienes, por así decirlo, las aptitudes del navegador.

Más información: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: Obtenía todos los valores vacíos. Tuve que reinstalar el archivo browscap.ini, ahora ya funciona correctamente.

Comment: Me alegro hayas solucionado @Piropeator. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola esta de moda el navegador brave y creo que hara mucho daño, podriais decirme si he logrado aislarlo en esta pagina:
https://abiertos.es/prueba8.php